# How to force the htm5 game to landscape using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to lock the game in landscape in android and ios devices. so that if a player try to play in portrait mode. It should be forced to be in landscape mode for that i tried to do something like this

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange resize', function(event){
    if(event.orientation) {
        if (event.orientation == 'landscape') {
            if (window.rotation == 90) {
                rotate(this, -90);
            } else {
                rotate(this, 90);
            }
        }
    }
    });
function rotate(el, degs) {
    iedegs = degs/90;
    if (iedegs < 0) iedegs += 4;
    transform = 'rotate('+degs+'deg)';
    iefilter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation='+iedegs+')';
    styles = {
        transform: transform,
        '-webkit-transform': transform,
        '-moz-transform': transform,
        '-o-transform': transform,
        filter: iefilter,
        '-ms-filter': iefilter
    };
    $(el).css(styles);
}
```

But it was not forcing to landscape when i am in portrait mode. Could any one help me out